# LSTM unit: cell state dimension

Tags: keras, rnn, lstm

When we fit an LSTM model, each LSTM has a cell state which contains the information we want. I am wondering what's the dimension in the cell state (i.e. cell state itself should be a vector, then how large is the vector?)?

[image]
(from http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/ )

i.e. In the above architecture, how do we determine the dimension of the matrix `Wc`?

If I am using Keras package, how do I find the Cell state dimensions of each LSTM unit? Is it something that one can adjust?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Keras, the first argument in LSTM gives the dimensionality of the cell state.

Comment: Feel free to correct me but the first argument is "units", which is the number of LSTM neurons in the layer. Source: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm

Comment: In this case, neurons = dimensionality.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the next hidden state $h_t$ is produced by applying pointwise scalar operations to the next cell state $C_t$. (The precise formula $h_t = o_t * \tanh(C_t)$ can be found in the blog post you link to.) Therefore, the cell state and the hidden state have the same dimensionality.